# Aplicar los cambios de estado (collapse/expand) de una columna en un Grid Panel

Tags: extjs

Mi probela es que consigo recibir la información del estado de la columna con el getState pero cuando uso el applyState no me aplica los cambios realizados.

```
   getState: function () {
        var result;
        result = Ext.grid.Panel.superclass.getState.call(this);
        return result;
   },
   applyState : function (state) {
        if(state.extendedNodes !== undefined){
             var nodes = state.expandedNodes;
        }else{
          var nodes = [];
        }    
          for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if(typeof nodes[i] != 'undefined') {
                    this.expandPath(nodes[i]);
                }
          }
      },
```

Toda ayuda se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final conseguí solucionarlo, el problema era que estaba llamado a Ext.grid.Panel cuando en realidad tendría que estar llamando a Ext.grid.GridPanel. os dejo el código:

```
  getState: function () {
        console.dir(\"called super getState\");
        var result;
        result = Ext.grid.GridPanel.superclass.getState.call(this);
        console.dir(result);
        return result;
      },


   applyState: function(state){
        Ext.grid.GridPanel.prototype.applyState.call(this, state);
        var collapsed = state.collapsed;
        //restore collapsed state
      },
```

Otra opcion más corta y más rápida es crear un new Ext.grid.GridPanel en vez de crear un new Ext.grid.Panel y tener que sobrescribir estas configuraciones.
Espero haberme explicado bien y que esto le sirva de ayuda a alguien.